# Javascript: onbeforeunload is not working

Tags: javascript

What is wrong in the following code?

```
<script language="javascript">
    function abreJanela() {
        var janela = window.open("http://www.google.com", "janela", "width=700, height=600");

        janela.onbeforeunload = function() {
            alert("Windows was closed");

        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of `onbeforeunload` is to return a string, which is (usually) used to prompt the user. Other actions, like `alert`, may be (and usually are) ignored. Please see [the Mozilla Developer Network documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload):

> Since 25 May 2011, the HTML5 specification states that calls to window.alert(), window.confirm(), and window.prompt() methods may be ignored during this event. See the HTML5 specification for more details.

Comment: But why the code still not working when i change this: `janela.onbeforeunload = function() {
            alert("Window was closed");` to this `janela.onbeforeunload = function() {
            return "Window was closed";`

Comment: Try using `addEventListener`. From the same page: "You can and should handle this event through [window.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and the [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) event. More documentation is available there."